# Postgresql pg_dump cmd:too many command-line arguments (first is "change\BF_2-UB_9-CLEAN.dump")

Tags: postgresql, cmd, pg-dump

trying to take a dump using cmd:

```
$ pg_dump -Fc -U postgres -d cleardb >> C:\ENV\backup\20235\CLEAN.dump
```

but getting error as:

```
pg_dump: too many command-line arguments (first is "change\BF_2-UB_9-CLEAN.dump")
Try "pg_dump --help" for more information.
```

expecting to taking a dump after this cmd followed by password

Comment: Are you sure you copied and pasted both of those lines correctly?  It is weird that the reported error is similar to, but not the same as, the path you tried to write to.

Comment: Try `-f C:\ENV\backup\20235\CLEAN.dump`  instead of `>>  C:\ENV\backup\20235\CLEAN.dump`